# Can't draw my HTML5 canvas until page reload (on Google Chrome only)

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I can't draw my HTML5 canvas until the page reload on Google Chrome only, it works fine on Firefox.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c5mGL/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1202" height="602" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

```
(function () {
'use strict';

window.onload = function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  function reset() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 150);
    ctx.lineTo(450, 50);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  reset();
};
})();
```

Everything works fine while displaying in the fiddle, since the HTML web page is embedded in an iframe.
But if you look directly the generated web page http://jsfiddle.net/c5mGL/5/show/, the problem occurs.

**Reproduction steps**: Open Google Chrome, open a new tab, go to http://jsfiddle.net/c5mGL/5/show/, press enter and you see nothing (no error in the JavaScript console neither). Now refresh the tab and you see the line in the canvas.

It looks to be because of the size of the HTML5 canvas, since if you use a smaller canvas (300 * 200), it works well.

An idea anyone?

Many thanks.

Edit: Google Chrome version: Version 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: I followed your reproduction steps and there's no difference between Chrome version Version 28.0.1500.72 and Firefox.

Comment: Works on first attempt no need to reload page!

Comment: I see the line without refreshing. I'm running Chrome 30 dev.

Comment: What's your chrome version?

Comment: How big is you extensions stack. Try trimming them.

Comment: I opened a issue on Google chrome [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265794)

Comment: you shouldn't use window.onload = ..., use window.addEventListener. Especially if you are using 3rd party libraries, and ESPECIALLY if you are a 3rd party library.

Comment: Adrian, I disabled every google chrome extensions

Comment: have you flipped your code to addEventListener?

Comment: Adrian, ok done, the problem remains [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/c5mGL/7/show/)

Comment: It's probably a driver problem. Try disabling the Canvas hardware acceleration, chrome://flags/ or switch channels to the dev channel to see if the problem has already been fixed.

Comment: Adrian, you got it, that was that (canvas hardware acceleration). Maybe you should write an answer I would "validate" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

It could be a driver problem.
Try disabling the Canvas hardware acceleration, chrome://flags/ AND switch channels to the Dev channel to see if the problem has already been fixed.

Comment: one other tweak you could try, set the width to a 8/16/32/64 'friendly' width.  say 1216, you might bypass the driver glitch.

Comment: Setting the flag "Disable accelerated 2D canvas" to "enabled" fixed the issue.